# How to use offset().top with a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

Thanks for taking a look at my issue. I have a nav bar with position fixed, and a ul. I want to apply a class to each li individually when the offset().top of the nav is greater than the offset().top of each li. As the user scrolls down the page, each li should be 1) shown and 2) be given a class so that it animates its way onto the page.

```
var nav = $('#nav').offset().top;

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio_pieces'), (function(piece){
  console.log(piece);
  if (piece.offset().top < nav) {
    $(piece).show().addClass("rollIn");
  }
}));
```

I am trying to accomplish this with a forEach loop; however, the console tells me that piece.offset is not a function. Each piece represents an li with the class 'portfolio_pieces'. Is there another way to accomplish this, or am I missing anything that isn't allowing offset to work on these li elements?

Thank you so much for reading, if you have any ideas please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use [jQuery offset method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), than it should be applied to jQuery element. In your case:

```
$(piece).offset().top
```

If you want to stick to pure Javascript, than check [offsetTop property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop):

```
piece.offsetTop
```

Explanation: You used Javascript's [getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method, which:

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names

And therefor you cannot apply jQuery methods to any of them.